# Deleting Rows and Adding Corresponding Elements in a List

Tags: arrays, list, csv

I'm extracting data from a CSV with 5 rows and 5 columns.

Some rows have "NA" in them.  How do I ignore the rows with "NA"
completely, so I can just loop through the items without the NA?

For example

```
print("Year  Age Scholarship Academic Stipend")
print("1982  20  $20000.00   $1000.00")
print("1983  21  $25000.00   NA")
print("1984  22  $30000.00   $500.00")
print("1982  20  $16000.00   $200.00")
print("1983  21  $17500.00   $600.00")
```

I extracted individual lists with all these elements:

```
Year = [1982,1983,1984,1982,1983]
Age = [20,21,22,20,21]
Scholarship = [20000, 25000, 30000, 16000, 17500]
Stipend_Amount = [1000, NA, 500, 200, 600]
```

I tried using:

```
while NA in Stipend_Amount:
      values.remove(NA)
```

but this changes the # of elements in Stipend_Amount. I want to keep all my lists the same number of elements, by ignoring the rows in CSV file containing the "NA."

Comment: It is better to create a separate thread for your second question, so that people can provide a complete and helpful answer for both. Please create the second question to ask "Question 2" and edit this one to remove the second question.

Comment: Thanks! I made the separation.